# using MPI_Comm_split into an if statement

Tags: mpi

When I run this code with one process, it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Comm SubWorld;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int Rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Rank);

    if (Rank == 0)
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, Rank, &SubWorld);

    cout << Rank << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 0

But when I run it with more than one process, the output is "1" only!!.

This code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Comm SubWorld;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int Rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Rank);

    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, Rank, &SubWorld);

    cout << Rank << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs two lines with "0" and "1" in some order.

So, the question is what the wrong in the first code when I run it with more than one process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Comm_split()` is a collective operation, and it must be invoked by *all* the MPI tasks of the communicator (`MPI_COMM_WORLD` here).

So what really happens in your first example running on multiple nodes is that MPI task 0 hangs in `MPI_Comm_split()`

Comment: Great, you mean after calling this routine over MPI_COMM_WORLD, each process into MPI_COMM_WORLD should belongs to a splited MPI_Comm. Right?

Comment: yes. note on some tasks, the new communicator might be `MPI_COMM_NULL` and i am not sure it would be correct to call that a splited MPI_Comm. fwiw, `MPI_Comm_create_group()` can be used to create a communicator, and it is invoked only by process of the group, which is a subset of the original communicator.